# Visual Studio 2019 Community cannot create WPF App (.NET Core)

Tags: wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

When I try to create a WPF App (.NET Core) in Visual Studio 2019 the following error appears:
[image]

When I go to the spot I have it checked off already;
[image]

Yes, I have restarted both VS and my computer.  I can create Class Libraries using .NET Core 3.0.  I have updated Visual Studio to 16.2.3.

All my search points back to the checkbox that is already checked.

Comment: try and download Visual studio 2019 preview, works for me there. Preview stands for Preview features not preview functions

Comment: @ComputerAidedTradingSystems thanks that did!  If you want to place this as the answer and I will mark it off